# Write to a txt file right to left

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to write a message in Hebrew to a text file. I tried the following:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path + FileName))
{
    sw.WriteLine(sms);
}
```

However, the message comes out left to right. How can I write right to left?

Comment: There is no such a thing as "right to left" byte organization within a file. Just write all text to file as you did (this will be an internal representation) and then display it accordingly wherever you want after reading it from the file.

Comment: The user's PC needs to be setup with the language first and it's actually a setting in Notepad. Here is some reference that might help achieve what you want: http://www.tertullian.org/rpearse/RightToLeft_Syriac/right_to_left.htm

Answer (score 2):

A string is an Array of Chars so you can

```
Char[] tempArray = sms.ToCharArray()
Array.Reverse(tempArray)
sms = new String(tempArray)
```

This should reverse the array therefore when you write it will read right to left.

Comment: Writing right-to-left is totally different from Reversing a text! Right to left and Left to right are two style of writing! The questioner is asking how to write in a text file right to left!

Answer (score 2):

well, it doesn't really matter how you write them in.

Here's a little example:

```
void Main()
{
    string lines = "First line.\r\nSecond line.\r\nThird line.";
    var = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test_eng.txt");
    file.WriteLine(lines);
    file.Close();

    string hebrew = @"מספרים רצים מימין לשמאל ?";
    file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test_heb.txt");
    file.WriteLine(hebrew);
    file.Close();
}
```

Upon opening the files, you'll find that hebrew is hebrew, and display from right to left.

Are you experiencing any funny behavior?

You can also try defining your string culture to hebrew:

```
 // Creates and initializes the CultureInfo which uses the international sort.
  CultureInfo myCIintl = new CultureInfo( "he", false );
```

More on that [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Some more thinking -> I doubt the above will change much for the display, it'll be more useful for dates for example. But atm, I'm not able to see hebrew on my console output ... What are you outputting to? Just txt, HTML, or something else?